# How do I make a random selection in a spreadsheet using more than one criteria

Tags: openoffice, spreadsheet, openoffice-calc, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet created in OpenOffice (V3.3.0 in Windows 7 32 bit) that I use as a database of my DVD collection. After asking a [question in SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/239604/spreadsheet-forumula-questions-to-pick-a-random-dvd), I have it so it can pop up a random title from my collection for the times I can’t make up my mind what to watch. It uses the following formula:

```
=INDIRECT("A"&RANDBETWEEN(2;COUNTA(A1:A1048576)))
```

This selects a random value between the start and end of my DVD’s and displays the name. This works fine but I now want to expand on it to make it a bit more sophisticated.

Every time I watch a DVD, I mark down the date in a column in the spreadsheet. I now want the random selection to pick one that I haven’t seen in, say, the last six months.

I may expand on this in the future to, for example, select a random one that I haven’t seen in the last 6 months AND is a comedy (I also have a column of the film’s genre).

Any pointers on how to do this will be gratefully received.

Answer (score 2):

You need to now add another column containing the date you last watched said movie, as well as the genre.  I don't know how to automate this off the top of my head, but you can keep re-calculating the formula until a random selection is found.

What you need to do is add a few `IF` clauses to see if the selected movie matches the genre you want, and if the last play date exceeds a certain date from now.

To do this, what I would do is enter my criteria in a few cells, and store a random cell's location in another one.  Then, you can do something like:

`=IF((Last Watched - Today) > 6 Months, IF(Genre = Selected Genre, TITLE))`

To get these values, you can use the `OFFSET` function to offset your `INDIRECT` by a certain amount of rows/columns.  Basically, you would replace the values I put in that formula with a new `OFFSET` value.  The only caveats to this method is that you're not guaranteed to get a title each time - you may have to keep re-calculating the random cell until it finds one that matches your criteria (I don't know how to automate this off the top of my head without macros).

---

Just for more details, let's say you put the random cell containing a DVD's title in cell `A1`.  You could replace the TITLE in the previous formula with `INDIRECT(A1)`.  If the genre is in the column beside it, replace it with `OFFSET(INDIRECT(A1), 0, 1)`.  You can then update just the random value in cell A1, and it will match against your criteria automatically.  Furthermore, you can set your criteria in a number of static cells, so you could update that on-the-fly as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. First, filter the list of DVDs into a smaller list of "Haven't watched in a while", using similar conditionals as Breaththrough suggests: something like `=FILTER(A1:A1048576, (Last Watched - Today) > 6 Months, (Genre = Selected Genre, TITLE))`
2. Then apply your existing random selector function — `=INDIRECT("B"&RANDBETWEEN(2;COUNTA(B1:B1048576)))` , changed to column `B` (the new filtered list) — to find just one movie to watch.